# Merging two entities when querying in Room Database android

Tags: android, android-room

Let's say we have User and Order entity

```
@Entity
public class User{
   int id;
   String name;
}
@Entity
public class Order{
   int id;
   int userId;
   String meal;
}
```

So when i query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
public List<User> loadUsers();
```

I want this output:

```
{"user":{"id":"","name":"",
"order":{"id":"","userId":"","meal":""}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Relation* annotation for this problem. Note, the official documentation says [[official reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation)]:

> The type of the field annotated with Relation must be a List or Set.

```
@Entity
public class User{
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   String name;
   @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "orderId", entity = Order.class)
   List<Order> orders;
}

@Entity
public class Order{
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   int userId;
   String meal;
}
```